# Solaris equivalent SED matching optional end string

Tags: regex, sed, solaris

Given the following input strings:

```
Subject: C=AU, ST=Queensland, L=Brisbane, O=Organisation, OU=Branch, CN=Root CA/emailAddress=Support@mydept.qld.gov.au
Subject: C=AU, ST=Queensland, L=Brisbane, O=Organisation, OU=Branch, CN=machine.mydept.qld.gov.au
```

on Linux with the sed command:

```
echo $string | sed -n '/Subject:/s/.*CN=\(.*\)\([\/?].*\|$\)/\1/p'
```

I get the following:

```
Root CA
machine.mydept.qld.gov.au
```

Attempting the same operation on Solaris gives me no response whatsoever.
Changing the pattern to

```
/Subject:/!d;s/.*CN=\(.*\)\([\/].*\)/\1/p
```

gives me the Root CA but fails to deliver the item where the remainder of the string is the required pattern (ie.  there is no /emailaddress appended to the CN= field)

Can someone please assist in a solaris/basic regular expression syntax to help resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use awk instead of sed:

```
echo $string | nawk '/Subject:/ {sub(".*CN=",""); sub("/.*",""); print}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a /usr/ucb/sed on your Solaris?  Often Solaris provides two versions of standard UNIX commands; a system V version and a bsd version.  The bsd versions are mostly the basis of the ones used in Linux.  This is just a guess, as I don't have access to a Solaris machine to test with, but it's what I remember from years ago.

Comment: Most Unix commands in Linux are Gnu ones, not that much based on BSD but having their own extensions and specificities.

Comment: Well yes, true, but their lineage tends to be BSD-ish rather than sys V-ish.